# AngularJS: Display one specific object in an array at a time

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angularjs

I want to display only one specific object from this JSON array at a a time:

```
{"records":[
   {"Name":"Pogrom wichra - Ole\u015bnica ","Desc":"Dystans: ok 7km (bieg w stylu poligonu s\u0142u\u017cb specjalnych Polski) Trasa: woda, b\u0142oto, trz\u0119sawisko, g\u0119ste zaro\u015bla, przeszkody naturalne i sztuczne http:www.pogromwichra.pl","Image":"9833.jpg"},
   {"Name":"Bieg herosa ? Pustynia B\u0142\u0119dowska","Desc":"Dystans: opcja do wybrania 9 km, 10kmp\u0142aski lub z przeszkodami, bieg 3 i 9 godzinny Trasa: piasek, piasek, piasek, wzniesienia, przeszkody naturalne i sztuczne www.biegherosa.pl","Image":"6273.jpg"},
   {"Name":"Dycha na 5 ? Pi\u0105tkowice (ko\u0142o Pabianic)","Desc":"Dystans: 10km z niespodziank\u0105 Trasa: nawierzchnia utwardzona ok. 5%, drogi i \u015bcie\u017cki gruntowe 95%. Na trasie do pokonania tor motokrosowy z ostrymi podbiegami i zbiegami po nier\u00f3wnym pod\u0142o\u017cu. Obcinek bardzo trudny technicznie. www.koronapabianice.pl ","Image":"5383.jpg"},
   {"Name":"Bieg rze\u017aniczka (ma\u0142y rze\u017anik) ? Cisna (Bieszczady)","Desc":"Dystans: ok. 27km Trasa: do\u015b\u0107 trudna trasa g\u00f3rska, chocia\u017c przepi\u0119kna i malownicza www.biegrzeznika.pl\/rzezniczek\/","Image":"4640.jpg"},
   {"Name":"Runmageddon ? wiele miast w Polsce","Desc":"Dystans: 6, 12, 21km Trasa: woda, b\u0142oto, ogie\u0144, bagno, przeszkody linowe, sko\u015bne i pionowe \u015bciany, zasieki, okopy www.runmageddon.pl","Image":"7378.jpg"},{"Name":"GROM CHALLENDE - SI\u0141A I HONOR - O\u015brodek Szkolenia Poligonowego GROM Gr","Desc":"Dystans: 20km Trasa: mega wyczerpuj\u0105ca, jest tam wszystko o czym by\u015b pomy\u015bla\u0142 ?. Start tylko zespo\u0142owy (2-osobowy), limit czasowy 5 godzin","Image":"8815.jpg"},
   {"Name":"Biegowa bitwa o \u0141\u00f3d\u017a - \u0141\u00f3d\u017a ","Desc":"Dystans: ok.13km Trasa: woda, b\u0142oto, trz\u0119sawisko, g\u0119ste zaro\u015bla, przeszkody naturalne i sztuczne facebook.com\/bitwaolodz","Image":"7019.jpg"},
   {"Name":"Bieg po wygas\u0142ych wulkanach -Z\u0142otoryja","Desc":"Dystans: 13-14km Trasa: Trasa ekstremalna w terenie zalesionym, b\u0142oto, rowy melioracyjne, trz\u0119sawisko, dno jeziora, przeszkody sztuczne i naturalne, strome podbiegi. www.biegwulkanow.pl","Image":"8465.jpg"}
]}
```

In my Javascript file, I only put the object on the scope.

```
$http.get("link/to/my/json/file").success(function (response) {
    $scope.recommends = response.records;
});
```

Finally, my HTML looks more or less like this:

```
<article class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="polecanybieg">
    <div ng-repeat="recomended in recommends">
        <h1>{{recomended.Name}}</h1><hr>
        <img class="recomendedrunimg" ng-src="../run/{{recomended.Image}}"><br><br>
        <p>{{recomended.Desc}}</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

All I want to do is to display a single record at time, and then change it by clicking on some button on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `ng-click`, you can call a setter function on the controller to store the selected `recomended` item in a variable

then using `ng-show` decide if should display the additional data ( only when the current `recomended` object equals to the selected one )

## http://jsfiddle.net/kcbxg14p/1/

**js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.setSelectedItem = function (item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
    };
        
    $scope.recommends = [{
        "Name": "Pogrom wichra - Ole\u015bnica ",
            "Desc": "Dystans: ok 7km (bieg w stylu poligonu s\u0142u\u017cb specjalnych Polski) Trasa: woda, b\u0142oto, trz\u0119sawisko, g\u0119ste zaro\u015bla, przeszkody naturalne i sztuczne http:www.pogromwichra.pl",
            "Image": "9833.jpg"
    }, 
    ... 
    ];

});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="recomended in recommends"> 
        <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setSelectedItem(recomended)"> Click to view {{recomended.Name}} </a>

            <div class="well" ng-show="selectedItem == recomended">
                 <h1>{{recomended.Name}}</h1>

                <hr>
                <img class="recomendedrunimg" ng-src="../run/{{recomended.Image}}">
                <br>
                <br>
                <p>{{recomended.Desc}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You really saved me hours of working ;) need to learn a bit more about ng-show. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only one `recommend` at a time, why looping?

Following the Angular philosophy, you should **declare** what to show already in the page. In this case

```
<span>{{recommend}}</span>
```

where `[[Controller]].recommend` is a variable exposed from the relative controller, should be enough.

Leaving out the fetching part, assuming `[[Controller]].records` is already a list of objects, then

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as Ctrl">
    <span>{{Ctrl.recommend}}<span> - <span ng-click="Ctrl.setNextRecord()">&gt;</span>
</div>
```

and

```
angular.module(<your module name here>)
    .controller("MainCtrl", [function () {
        var self = this;
        self.records = [ ... ];
        self.recommend = records[0];
        self.currentIndex = 0;
        self.setNextRecord = function () {
            var nextIndex = currentIndex < self.currentIndex - 2 ? currentIndex + 1 : 0;
            self.currentIndex = nextIndex;
            return self.recommend = records[self.currentIndex];
        };
    }]);
```

**WARNING**, I couldn't test the code.